# Multiple subdomains with one content

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain

I'm using Wordpress and what I want is to have to many subdomains that load the same site with the same content.

Example: http://teensdigest.com/

You can access the same content in the aff1.teensdigest.com or aff2.teensdigest.com ect ect...

I created the subdomain on my cpanel but when I click on the posts i redirect from aff1.domain.ltd to domain.ltd/post ...

I want that user continue stay at aff1.domain.ltd/post

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a domain alias which are called **Parked Domains** in cpanel. A domain alias will mirror the primary website but will still use the required domain.

Be careful as search engines do not like this as it is considered as duplicate content. [Read More](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en)

Comment: I tested this but it keep redirect into the main page not in the subdomain. Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 0):

I'm investigating a similar question, and found the [WP Subdomains (Revisited) plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-subdomains-revisited/).

Is has this option in its settings:

> **Keep Pages on Subdomain**
>
> Activate this to have links to your normal pages, not Subdomain or Category Tied, remain on the subdomain being viewed.
>
> Note: This could be bad for SEO as some search engines will see this as duplicate pages.

The plugin requires a wildcard for subdomains of some sort.  I'll leave that as a host-specific thing to solve.